# How To Delete Image File in Android sdk Version Lower Than 30

Tags: android

I am trying to delete the image By Its URI because I Have an image's Uri.
But it gave me This Error

```
android.app.RecoverableSecurityException: com.example.xyz has no access to content://media/external/images/media/206362
```

I am using this method to delete a file in my Pictures folder.

```
    private boolean deleteFile(Uri imagePath) {
    ContentResolver resolver = contextWeakReference.get().getContentResolver();
    int noOfRawDeleted = 0;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
        noOfRawDeleted = resolver.delete(imagePath, null);
    }else{
        noOfRawDeleted = resolver.delete(imagePath,null,null );
    }
    return noOfRawDeleted > 0;
}
```

Comment: You should google for that exception and then add the necessary code to continue the delete after user agreed. Code has been published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android Q and above, trying to delete an file which is owned by another app will throw a [RecoverableSecurityException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/RecoverableSecurityException). You must catch such exception and use its [IntentSender](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentSender) to request the delete permission for the target file.

```
public void delete(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    try {
        context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
    } catch (SecurityException exception) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

            if (exception instanceof RecoverableSecurityException) {
                final IntentSender intent = ((RecoverableSecurityException)exception).getUserAction()
                        .getActionIntent()
                        .getIntentSender();
                
                startIntentSenderForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0, null);
                return;
            }
        }

        throw exception;
    }
}
```

More details in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#remove-item).

Comment: **Thank you Very Much for this help :) **